# while creating aws s3 buckets in git bash I am getting following error

Tags: amazon-web-services, git

> make_bucket failed: s3://sadasdsd An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The authorization header is malformed; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting "/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request".

I am not getting how to resolve it

Comment: How are you sending the command? Are you using the AWS CLI? How are credentials being provided?